# Filtering on multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to build a row chart which groups people by attribute "sector" using D3.js and DC.js. I've been able to filter on one sector but unsure how to add multiple sectors per person, and group based on that.
For example:

Person : Sector

John : Electricity , Mining

Kim : Mining, Financials , Electricity

The electricity row would then have 2 entries, Mining 2 and Financials 1.

Current code grouping on one attribute:

```
// row chart Day of Week
var dayOfWeek = facts.dimension(function (d) {

    if(d.mag == "Electricity"){
    return "Electricity"}

    else if(d.mag == "Mining"){
    return "Mining"}

    else {
    return "Financials"}    
});

// row chart day of week


dayOfWeekChart.width(710)
    .height(220)
    .margins({top: 5, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20})
    .dimension(dayOfWeek)
    .group(dayOfWeekGroup)
    .colors(d3.scale.category10())
    .label(function (d){
        return d.key;
    })
    .title(function(d){return d.value;})
    .elasticX(true)
    .xAxis().ticks(10);
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: how do you want to show 2 entries ? with count or different bars ? https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/ this may help you

Comment: Do you want to apply the filter via Crossfilter (in which case you need to use filterFunction to filter to more than one value), or dc.js (in which case I think there is a way to do it more easily)?

Comment: In this case, I want to have 3 bars, representing (mining, electricity, financials). The count of Mining being 2, electricity 2 and financials 1. Not sure whether to use the filterfunction or dc.js, wanting an elegant solution. thanks